# scope of ng-model in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

Here's the html part...

```
<body ng-controller="homeController">
<div id="happyValentines" ng-model="myText"> {{ myText }}
```

I don't get why this works...

```
$scope.myText = "fksdm kdsmfk msldfkm kdfm ksdmf lsmdflm ";
$scope.changeHeight = function(elem) {
var body = document.body;
var height = 0;
var right = 0;
var opacity = 0; ...
```

But this doesn't...

```
$scope.changeHeight = function(elem) {
  var body = document.body;
  var height = 0;
  var right = 0;
  var opacity = 0;
  body.style.opacity = 0;
  var index = 0;
  var str = "fksdm kdsmfk msldfkm kdfmksdmf lsmdflm ";
  function frame() {
    index += 2;
    $scope.myText = str.substr(0, index);
    height += 4;
    if (right < 60) { 
      right += 1;
      elem.style.marginRight = right + "px";
    }
    opacity += .01;
    elem.style.height = height + "px";
    elem.style.opacity = opacity;
    body.style.opacity = opacity;
    if (opacity >= 1) {
      clearInterval(id);
    $scope.addButtons();
    // document.createElement....
    }
  }
    var id = setInterval(frame, 30);
  }
```

I'm quite new to angular and would like to know what angular construct is behind this, or why this is the case.

Comment: You haven't assigned `myText` a value in the second one as it is defined in a function `frame()` which is never called.

Comment: well it should work if your `changeHeight` function gets called and then in that function you call `frame()`, but you do not show all the code there so we do not know if you are calling them or not.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd code you have declared function 'changeHeight', and inside that you are setting the value of 'myText'. but on the page you have not called 'changeHeight' function so it'll not call that function and the value of 'mytext' won't be set.
try calling function 'changeHeight' on the page using ng-init or ng-click or ng-change a/c to situation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: ng-model is mainly used for form elements and is basically a deluxe version of using `onchange` events for get value from forms to the model and a `$watch` to get the value from the model to the form element. You don't need it just to display a value on the screen.

Second: You shouldn't modify the document or DOM in the controller. That's the directives responsibility (or maybe a service if it's document element modifications).

Regarding your second code block I don't get why you have a "`function frame()`" inside the `changeHeight` method. And the code is incomplete and you never actually call the `frame()` method that sets the `$scope.myText`.

Please provide complete code to get better help.

Comment: I updated the frame function to show more of what I'm doing.  It's basically an animation.  Why not modify the DOM in the controller?  I'll look up directives.  Thanks and let me know if you have a suggestion for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Because it's not the controller responsibility. The controller is basically just the glue between the view and the model. It does not change the look of the view it just provides the content to it and react to events so you can update your models. 

Directives are more for modifying the DOM.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the animation, but I think you might solve it with ´ngAnimation´ and using existing directives like ´ngShow´, ´ngHide´, ´ngIf´, etc.